# Transforming dataframe with pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple data frame:

[image]

I would like to transform it to the form that looks like this:

[image]

I have been trying to thinker with pivot_table but with now luck. I am not entirely sure if the pivot table able to do it.

Comment: I think you need `get_dummies`, check dupe.

Comment: If some problem, let me know.

Comment: Yes. Exactly what I need. Thank you.